# Cannot mount read only Kubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: networking, 18.04, mount, kubuntu, cifs

I am trying to mount my network share at startup. This is what i have in fstab:

```
[source] /media/MyDrive cifs username="ID",password="Passwd",uid=1000,gid=1000,sec=ntlmssp,vers=1.0  0       0
```

and when i execute sudo mount -a command i get:

```
cannot mount [source] read only
```

if in try vers 2.0 and higher, i get an error host is down.

Anyone with the fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out cifs utility is not updated automatically when us updates roll out. So after i did `sudo apt-get upgrade cifs-utils`, it worked fine, i just changed it a little to

```
[source] [destination] cifs credentials=[creds file],rw,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlmssp,vers=1.0  0  0
```

and it worked without a hitch. So for everyone who is looking for solution to this, make sure you UPGRADE your cifs utility :)